# How to erase an element from a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to erase an element in a vector in C++ with the `erase` method like this:

```
player_animals.erase(second_parameter);
```

Please note that `second_parameter` is an integer `e.g. 2`

and the `player_animals` is a vector of Animal pointers defined like this: `vector<Farm::Animal *>`animals_;

and the error I get about erase is:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::__1::vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::erase [with 
_Tp=Farm::Animal *, _Allocator=std::__1::allocator<Farm::Animal *>]" matches the argument 
list -- argument types are: (unsigned int) -- object type is: std::__1::vector<Farm::Animal 
*, std::__1::allocator<Farm::Animal *>>
```

The code where I use the erase method is as follows:

```
 if (animal_to_be_sold->getType() == SellCommand::SELL_FARM_ANIMAL)
            {
                Farm::FarmAnimal* animal_to_be_sold = static_cast<FarmAnimal*> (animal_to_be_sold);
                player.putAnimalInSold(animal_to_be_sold);
                player_animals.erase(second_parameter); 
                player.addMoney(SellCommand::FARM_ANIMAL_PRICE);
            }

            else
            {
                player.addMoney(SellCommand::PET_PRICE);
                player_animals.erase(second_parameter); 

            }
```

How could I fix this so I can use the erase method to remove an element in the vector at a position

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work because std::vector::erase function requires iterator:

```
player_animals.erase(player_animals.begin() + second_parameter);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to not do anything, after getting the size of the vector before and after erase, it is the same

Comment: Please make sure that you are using the function size() instead of capacity() otherwise it should work unless the second_parameter is off limits of vector.